# Почему не могу поставить высоту на flexbox в процентах?

Tags: css3, html5, flexbox

Почему не могу поставить высоту на flexbox в процентах???

```css
 .wrapper_two {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
 }

 .wrapper_video {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #000;
  justify-content: start;
  align-items: center;
 }

 .wrapper_text {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #888;
  width: 500px;
  height: 80%;
 }

 .sidebat_bomb {
  width: 100px;
  height: 90%;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #ccc;
  justify-content: end;
 }
```

```html
 <div class="wrapper_two">
  <div class="wrapper_video"></div>
  <div class="wrapper_text"></div>
  <div class="sidebat_bomb">
      <!-- <img src="img/bulb-48.png" alt="">
       <img src="img/bulb-48.png" alt=""> -->
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы задавать высоту в  процентах, эти проценты должны от чего отталкиваться...  а если `<div class="wrapper_two">` данный контейнер не имеет высоты, от куда дочерние будут высчитывать этот самый процент?

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper_two {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100px;
}

.wrapper_video {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #000;
  justify-content: start;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrapper_text {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #888;
  width: 500px;
  height: 80%;
}

.sidebat_bomb {
  width: 100px;
  height: 90%;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #ccc;
  justify-content: end;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper_two">
  <div class="wrapper_video">wrapper_video</div>
  <div class="wrapper_text">wrapper_text</div>
  <div class="sidebat_bomb">sidebat_bomb
    <!-- <img src="img/bulb-48.png" alt="">
       <img src="img/bulb-48.png" alt=""> -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, этого не знал =)

Comment: всегда пожалуйста...))